# Using crittercism with Unity

Tags: unity, exceptions, crittercism

I want to use [crittercism](https://www.crittercism.com/) with my Unity project. In Unity I am developing a game for iOS and Android platform. I did enough Google searching to come to the conclusion that Unity doesn't support this by itself and there aren't much tools out there to help me.

Can someone suggest a way to do it?

If not, is it possible for me to get access to the editor logs of Unity programmatically so that I can send these logs to my server directly. (I'll however still need to know when a crash occurs.)

I was thinking of a "hack". Please tell me if it is doable. On building the project, Unity creates an xcode project for iOS. I was thinking of opening the xcode project itself and putting the relevant commands to send the logs to crittercism, in case a crash occurs. However I am not able to think of a way to do this with Android.

Comment: You can *probably* use it just fine with their plugin system (assuming Unity pro).  See http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/PluginsForAndroid.html and http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/PluginsForIOS.html

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like crittercism offers any library that you could use with Unity. There's a chance that you could take the HTML5 version, which is in Javascript, and either rework or extract certain parts in order to use them in UnityScript, but I fear some of the error reporting will assume that it is running in a browser context and will be unable to communicate back with the server.

So I don't think there is any way you can use this tool from a Unity app directly. It might be worth contacting the developers and suggesting they support Unity in future. Your workaround for iOS might work.

I don't think that Debug.Log output appears in final builds of the game, so I am not sure how much use it will be to try and send those to your server. But there might be some log output you can use, and the different locations of the log files are here: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/9739/how-can-i-find-editor-log-file.html I don't know if the directory can be reached programmatically from within your code.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're interested in things like Crash Data, stack traces, tracking 3rd party vendors etc.  Another option to do this is to perhaps use [Loggly](http://loggly.com).  It's different from Crittercism it's geared more towards consume & visualizing game logs than automatically categorizing performance data but they have a [REST API](https://www.loggly.com/docs/http-endpoint/) which will allow you to use it in Unity and you can log the exact same information (transaction logs, device used, monitor service provider HTTP response times, crash/exception logs).